# .NET MAUI Shell customisation issues (iOS)

Tags: .net, maui

[image]

This is almost what I would like to end up. A custom back button and a single title. The code that generates this is:

```
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior  IsVisible="False" />
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>

<Shell.TitleView>

        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="1*,9*">
            <ImageButton Source="back.png" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked" ></Image>
            <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                      Text="123123123123"
                      TextColor="#ff8e00"
                      FontSize="24"
                      FontAttributes="Bold"
                      HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

Code behind:

```
async void ImageButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
}
```

Problems:

1 - I ended up using this awkward binding. When I use `VerticalStackLayout` nothing gets displayed, and when I use `HorizontalStackLayout` I cannot control Grid's width. Is there a better way you can recommend to achieve the same outcome ?

2 - How can I bind this ImageButton to usual back behaviour ?

Comment: why do you need any layout wrapping the Grid?

Comment: Doh... Works just well without the stack layout and binding, thank you. Any idea how can I bind the back button ?

Comment: what does `BackCommand` do?

Comment: I just want that ImageButton to do exactly what the old back button was doing. I am not sure how to make that possible.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#backwards-navigation

Comment: Ok `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");` but neither Clicked nor TapGestureRecogniser works for that ImageButton, does it get handled differently because it is in Shell.TitleView ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.   If you need further help, please post the relevant code

Comment: Please see the updated question. A breakpoint in the function does not get hit upon clicking the button.

Comment: that's because your label is on top of the button.  Place the Label in Column 1

Comment: That would stop me from centering the title, instead I went for ZIndex=1 which solved the problem. Sorry lots of trivial mistakes on this one and your help is greatly appreciated. All working as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have tried putting all of the code in a `ContentView` like this. With this you have a control and separates the title information from the rest of your code.

**ContentView**

```xml
<ContentView
    x:Class="MauiTest.Controls.TitleView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"
            Source="back.png" />
        <Label
            FontSize="24"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="123123123123"
            TextColor="#ff8e00" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

**Code Behind**

```cs
public partial class TitleView : ContentView
{
    public TitleView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }
}
```

You use it like this on individual pages

```cs
var backButtonBehavior = new BackButtonBehavior
{
    IsEnabled = false
};
Shell.SetBackButtonBehavior(this, backButtonBehavior);
Shell.SetTitleView(this, new TitleView());
```

And it looks like this on my iPhone simulator:
[image]